# Grid scrolls to top when any row is clicked in ext js

Tags: extjs, grid

I am facing a very strange problem. I have a grid and when i CLICK on any row then grid automatically goes to first record, though the row on which i click is selected but not focused.

The problem is strange because when i used that same grid as an example then there was no problem and everything works fine.

I really dont understand what could cause this problem? i haven't overridden any listeners to scroll to top either.

Comment: hi everyone... The problem is when i use the same grid in another example then there is no such problem. I really dont understand what could do that problem......I really hope somebody suggests something for my problem.

Comment: Also i noticed that in IE - whenever I clicked on grid row it will automatically scroll to top. In Mozilla firefox - if i click on space except grid row and then click on grid row then it will scroll to  top. I tried to create my page 5 times again and again but still same problem is still there.....Please SOMEBODY HELP ME.........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had following in my code which was causing it so remove this:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.GridView, {
     syncFocusEl : Ext.emptyFn
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work with ExtJs 4.0. I've got it working with the following. I haven't fully tested for unexpected side effects.

```
Ext.override(Ext.selection.RowModel, {
    onRowMouseDown: function (view, record, item, index, e) {
        this.selectWithEvent(record, e);
    }
});
```

The original method looks like this:

```
onRowMouseDown: function(view, record, item, index, e) {
    view.el.focus();
    this.selectWithEvent(record, e);
}
```