# How to prevent Ext.js from scrolling when leaving a cell

Tags: extjs

I'm actually having the opposite problem from [How to prevent extjs grid from scrolling when clicking on a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061392/how-to-prevent-extjs-grid-from-scrolling-when-clicking-on-a-cell)  When I select a grid cell, in my case a dropdown, select an option and then click elsewhere on the page it scrolls the page up so that that row is at the top of the page.

This is using Ext 4.1.1a.